# SimpleInjector : Register collection with InstanceCreator

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ioc-container, simple-injector

I'm trying to register a collection along with its instanceCreator. I wasn't able to find any overload for the `Container.Collection.Register` method which accepts an instanceCreator. If i try to run a loop and register a type along with its instanceCreator multiple times using the `Container.Register(instanceCreator, lifestyle)`, i'm unable to do it because i get the error that type cannot be registerd multiple times.

Basically what i'm trying to do is:

```
foreach(var item in items){
 Container.Register<ILogWriter>(instanceCreator, lifestyle)
}
```

I have multiple implementations of `ILogWriter` and each have their own different configurations which need to passed in the constructor, hence i need to use the instanceCreator overload.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Container.Collection.Register` is meant for registering the whole collection at once. For instance by using batch-registration and supplying a list of `Assembly` instances, or a list of `Type` instances.

What you are looking for, on the other hand, is registering a single item for a collection of instances. This is done using the `Container.Collection.Append` overloads:

```
container.Collection.Append<ILogWriter>(instanceCreator, lifestyle);
```