# Simple Injector: Unable to register generic types in the constructor when registering a collection

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ioc-container, simple-injector

I have a list of Funcs which contains the types and their arguments which i need to register to the container:

```cs
var LogCreaters = new List<Func<ILogFormat, FolderLocation, ILogWriter>>
{
    (fmt,path)=> new NlogWriter(new NlogConfiguration(fmt,path.logging)),
    (fmt,path)=> new DisplayWriter(fmt)
}
```

This is how I'm trying to register the collection:

```cs
container.Collection.Register<ILogWriter>(LogCreaters);
```

Followed by:

```cs
foreach (var item in LogCreater)
{
    container.Collection.Append<ILogWriter>(
        () => item(LogFormat, FolderLocation), LifeSpan.Scoped);
}
```

But `container.Verify()` throws the following exception:

> The configuration is invalid. Creating the instance for type Logger
>   failed. The constructor of type NlogWriter contains the parameter with
>   name 'config' and type NlogConfiguration, but NlogConfiguration is not
>   registered. For NlogConfiguration to be resolved, it must be
>   registered in the container.

What I'm guessing is that the type `NlogWriter` is registered in the container but it's constructor arguments are not getting registered in the process. How would i be able to register the `LogCreators` along with their constructors and the types in the constructor arguments to the container in my current scenario.

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60781095/simpleinjector-register-collection-with-instancecreator) question recently about how to register a collection, in which my question was answered but i guess i wasnt able to explain my current scenario properly, hence i'm posting this again with more detail.

TIA.

Comment: Hi Hamza, I read your question a couple of times and copied the posted code to a console application, but I don't understand the question, nor your code. The code doesn't compile and its unclear to me what you are trying to achieve. Please update your question and post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). A good way to do this is by recreating the problem in an empty console application, using the minimal amount of code that reproduces the problem and then post *that exact compilable code* here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Also describe in your question what the goal is of the `Func<ILogFormat, FolderLocation, ILogWriter>` delegates and show how its indented to be used. Who is calling this for instance.